# ¿Como relacionar dos usuarios en una tabla?

Tags: sql, adonisjs, adonis-4

Resulta que estoy intentando hacer una especie de **inbox** entre dos usuarios que en este caso no será en tiempo real... Tengo una Tabla `conversations` con  dos columnas en este caso `userone` y `usertwo`

El problema:

> Es que por más que lo intento no logro relacionar esos dos usuarios en la misma tabla, es decir los usuarios postean sus `id` pero no carga la relación con los usuarios...

Estoy utilizando adonis pero me vendría similar una explicación con LARAVEL o al menos me daría una idea ya que son muy parecidos

```
up () {
    this.create('conversations', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.integer('from_user_id')
      table.integer('to_user_id')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

Lucid model conversation

users(){
      return this.hasMany('App/Models/User')
      }

Lucid model User

conversation(){
      return this.belongsTo('App/Models/Conversation')
    }   


Controller Conversation

.where('from_user_id', user.id)
        .with('users')
        .fetch()

//En este caso los 'users' me salen en null
```

Comment: En este caso lo que estoy intentando  es crear una conversación entre dos usuarios, en una tabla tengo 

userone y usertwo

que se supone debería contener dos usuarios, el problema es que al cargar la relacion "users" me sale en Null a pesar de que ya definí la relacion muchos a muchos en el modelo, tengo la sensación de que esto ocurre por el nombre de las tablas siendo que al poner user_id si carga la relación de un usuario, el problema es que no puedo poner dos columnas repetidas en la tabla... Me gustaría saber como cargar los dos usuarios en una misma tabla...

Comment: Así es se supone que establecen entre quienes es la conversación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Recomendaciones para proceder**

- No veo por que deban existir 2 entidades de usuarios, ¿por qué lo digo?, bueno cuando almacenas un usuario este tiene tanto la posibilidad de ser **emisor** y **receptor**, entonces no creo que lo que intentas sea correcto, pues de lo contrario estarías redundando información por que el mismo usuario que registres en tu tabla emisor eventualmente lo tendrías que estar registrando también en la tabla emisor
- Si estas trabajando con una relación de *muchos a muchos*, entonces el método que se debe usar es: [belongsToMany](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/relationships#_belongs_to_many) como se indica en la documentación.

Entonces ¿cómo hacerlo?

Opino que tu estructura debería ser de este modo:

La migración de tu tabla `users` que almacene algo similar a esto:

Todos los usuarios de tu desarrollo pueden cumplir 1 o las 2 funciones que son emisor y receptor por tanto todos deben estar almacenados en la misma tabla.

```
up () {
    this.create('users', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.string('name')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }
```

Una segunda migración que se llamará `conversations` que almacenará los `id` de los 2 usuarios que interactúan en la platica así:

```
up () {
    this.create('conversations', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.integer('transmitter_id').unsigned().references('id').inTable('users')
      table.integer('receiver_id').unsigned().references('id').inTable('users')
      table.string('talk')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }
```

- De la anterior migración obtenemos que se almacenan 2 `ids` como llaves foráneas, ambas hacen referencia a la PK de la tabla `users`.
- Les colocamos nombres de columna distinto, para al momento de almacenarlos saber si ese `id` hace referencia a quien envía el mensaje o a quien lo recibe.

> Importante! No usaré para este ejemplo las relaciones de Lucid, pero tu eres libre de adaptar lo que aquí te muestro según tus necesidades.

Finalmente para poder hacer la consulta y obtener de la tabla `users` la información donde el `transmitter_id` sea igual a algo que le pasemos como equivalencia en el método `where()`

```
const platica = await Conversation.query()
         .select('users1.name AS Emisor', 'talk', 'users2.name AS Receptor')
         .join('users as user1', 'conversations.transmitter_id', '=', 'user1.id')
         .join('users as user2', 'conversations.receiver_id', '=', 'user2.id')
         .where('transmitter_id', 1)
         .fetch()
```

Con base en mi ejemplo deberías obtener algo como esto en la salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez hecho todos los puntos anteriores, te das cuenta de lo siguiente:

- Puedes almacenar múltiples pláticas entre 2 usuarios en una sola tabla, existiendo la posibilidad de repetir sus `id` lo cual indica que podrán platicar mas de una vez.
- Una sola tabla `users` debe almacenar a todos tus usuarios ya que al menos yo no le veo sentido a separarlos en 2 cuando todos tus usuarios cumplen el rol de enviar mensaje y/o recibir mensaje
- Usamos los métodos del *query builder* para construir la consulta *(por que en este momento no tengo una copia de Adonis para hacer mas pruebas)* pero es perfectamente válido si lo adaptas a lucid

**Finalmente**

A nivel de SQL la estructura que usé de ejemplo es:

**Tabla users**

```
CREATE TABLE users(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR(20)
);
```

**Tabla conversations**

```
CREATE TABLE conversations(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  transmitter_id INT,
  receiver_id INT,
  platica VARCHAR(30),
  CONSTRAINT fk_conversations_users1 FOREIGN KEY(transmitter_id) REFERENCES users(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_conversations_users2 FOREIGN KEY(receiver_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

> Espero te sirva por lo menos de guía

Comment: Hola! En cierta manera me diste una pequeña idea, el problema de este método es que el id de la conversación va a aumentar conforme los usuarios vayan platicando, es decir necesito que la conversación sea única, por ejemplo que en una conversación se almacenen muchas interacciones

Lo que tenía en mente era primero crear la conversación y luego relacionar esa conversación con los participantes para que de esta forma la conversación sea una y los participantes sean muchos

Comment: En esta estructura se almacenarían todos los participantes de la conversación, recordemos que por cada vez que eso suceda se generará un nuevo registro en la bd, puedes entonces agregar una columna mas a la tabla `conversations` que ayude a identificar a cada conversación @AntonioCGuzmán tal vez un `conversation_id`

Comment: Te agradezco mucho por tu respuesta! utilizé la estructura que me comentaste para comenzar e identificar la conversación, no obstante necesito dos tablas ya que requiero que el usuario remitente haga acciones unicas, no obstante añadí el id de la conversación a la tabla de los participantes y funcionó! muchas gracias